# API wrapper in ruby not taking arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, httparty

I am writing a library to interact with the [Elophant API](http://elophant.com) and my current wrapper to get `current game infomation` looks like this

```
require "httparty"

class Elophant
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'api.elophant.com'

    def initialize(name, region)
        @options = {query: {
            summoner_name: name,
            region: region,
            key: ENV["ELOPHANT_API_KEY"]
        }}
    end

    def self.current_game
        HTTParty.get("/v2/#{region}/in_progress_game_info/#{summoner_name}?key=#{key}", @options)
    end

    def self.summoner_info
        HTTParty.get("/v2/#{region}/summoner/#{summoner_name}?key=#{key}", @options)
    end
end
```

so i can call

```
elophant = Elophant.new
elophant.current_game("summoner_name", "OCE")
```

sending this info to my rails view like so

```
  def index
    elophant = Elophant.new
    @CurrentGame = elophant.current_game("summoner_name", "OCE")
  end
```

except rails throws this error

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

    base_uri 'api.elophant.com'

    def initialize(name, region)
        @options = {query: {
            summoner_name: name,
            region: region,
```

Comment: You have define the initializer of Elophant with two arguments. So when you call the Elophant.new you should provide the name and region value.

Comment: i thought the `@options` allowed me to get away with the syntax i used?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Elpohant` class like this:

```
elophant = Elophant.new("summoner_name", "OCE")
elophant.current_game
```

You have defined `Elophant` to have two arguments in the initializer, i.e. `summoner_name` and `region`. However you are passing these in the call to `current_game`.

If in your case, these parameters are local to method calls, and can change depending on the method being invoked, you may want to bring those parameters to the methods i.e. `current_game` in this case.

Comment: ok ive done that now its throwing an error saying it cant find the varible `region` althought im passing the @options and when trying`query.regions` it says it cant find `current_game` method

Comment: Ok missed that bit - both `current_game` and `summoner_info` are class methods, is there a reason you would want them to not be instance methods?

Comment: good point, althought trying `def summoner_info` returns the same error